Pyinstaller ошибка ModuleNotFound
Что пишу в CMD:

Импорты:

Ошибка:

что делать? я не знаю как добавить директорию для импортов. А так же дополнительных файлов(на всякий случай)
Вопрос: Как указать в pyinstaller при компиляции в exe файл сторонние библиотеки и дополнительные файла ( напишите два случая в ответе на мой основной вопрос а потом ответ) спасибо
Я пробывал искать в интернете
смотрел на ютубе
пробывал auto-py-to-exe
итог: ничего не изменилось

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Pyinstaller и ошибка ModuleNotFound

Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

ошибка при компиляции:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "passManager.py", line 8, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer'
импорты:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from random import choice
import os
import json
а так же  иногда при компиляции требуеться logo.ico которое я добавил в доп.файлы но всё равно ошибка либо импорт либо файл с logo помогите пж
